# Spring Reactive Restful APIs - Is it really a non-blocking model?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I know that is possible to build my entire Spring boot application in reactive way.

So if my application uses R2DBC, I can do something like:

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, UUID> {

 Flux<Person> findAllByStatus(PersonStatusEnum status);
}

....

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {
 
 private final PersonRepository repo;

 Flux<Person> findAllByStatus(PersonStatusEnum status){
   return repo.findAllByStatus(status);
 }
}

....

@RestController
@RequestMapping("person")
@RequiredArgsContructor
public class PersonController {
 private final PersonService service;
 
 @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<Flux<Person>> findAllByStatus(@PathVariable("status") PersonStatusEnum status){

   return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findAllByStatus(status));
 }


}
```

In the example above, I have 1000 records in my Person table, 900 of which have status 'ACTIVE'.

My end client wants to retrieve all people with 'ACTIVE' status. In this example, I'm not using best practices like pagination.

My end constumer uses declarative programming. (It can be a cURL, or a Java application that uses RestTemplate).

Somehow 900 is a huge amount of records for my application and from what I understand the backpressure in R2DBC will be performed automagically telling the database to send less data.

What is the guarantee that my end client will receive the 900 records if they are using declarative Programming?

Does my client also need to be Reactive? (Using Webclient, for example).

If not, is `RestController` blocked somehow, waiting until the Repository has finished querying the database so my client will ? How does the whole body comes to a non Reactive client?

I mean, the Reactive is supposed to be non blocking. But if a non Reactive client can consume a Reactive API, it has to block on some point of the code to send back the response.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this is a question for [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Spring Reactive API's are non-blocking if both sides are reactive. There is no automatic backpressure handling (perhaps except for server queuing unhandled items). The client sets the amount of data it requests. It can request 1 item and then request another each time it handles the previous one, or it can request unlimited ones, and WebFlux will queue the items that are unhanded.  Another option is to use apis such as limitRange on the server side, limiting the amount of data sent. Generally there is no magical backpressure control until you use an appropriate API to implement it.

Comment: @GonenI nice. What about the Json response to a non-reactive client? My server is supposed to block the Flux somewhere to map it to Json. So, if it's true, there's a blocking operation on server side. Furthermore, if it's true, it breaks the logic of programming a reactive server-side to "consume less resources" since I'm blocking a Thread to produce a Json response... or don't?

Comment: Non reactive clients block until the whole response is delivered. There will be one HTTP request and one response. The sending of the response on the server side will be a blocking operation for whatever server side thread is handling it. Any promises for more resource efficiency on reactive programming requires both sides to be reactive ( speak the same language )

Comment: @GonenI Not entirely sure. Because Webflux uses Netty async I/O capabilities to  write http responses. Therefore, depending on how well webflux is coded, it could "suspend" the response flux when the response is not consumed fast enough, even if the client is not reactive. Sure, it won't be fine-grained back-pressure (but anyway, HTTP protocol cannot do that. You'd need something like RSocket instead), but it at least stream data from database. But I am not sure, we should find a doc or the code that handles Async I/O in Webflux to be sure (or create an example that demonstrate it).

Answer (score 0):

That’s a good question. From what I understand, backpressure is a mechanism to control the flow of data between a producer and a consumer in a reactive system. It allows the consumer to signal the producer how many elements it can handle, and prevent it from being overwhelmed by too much data.

**If your end client is using declarative programming, it may not be able to handle backpressure properly. It may block the thread until it receives all the data from the reactive API, or it may lose some data if the buffer is full.**

**To avoid these problems, your end client should also use reactive programming, such as WebClient in Spring WebFlux. This way, it can communicate with the reactive API in a non-blocking and asynchronous way, and apply backpressure strategies such as buffering, dropping, or sampling.**

Comment: Consider that my end client is able to handle any amount of data. What about my application. If my application performs backpressure on the repository, and Reactive model is supposed to be non-blocking, how my end user is able to see 900 records in a Json (since my controller produces Json)? My application must be blocking the Flux somewhere waiting to the repository finishes querying data to produce the Json, or don't?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).